# Make single cell overlap

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have searched but couldnt find an answer.

Is there a way to make only one specific cell overlap other cell and the rest cells be laid out in default layout.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible very easily. You can make the views inside of the cell overlap the other cells. So just add a subview to your UITableViewCell that overlaps the cells bounds. You could for example use auto layout constraints to position them outside the view or you just give the cell a lower height than its subview.

Then you need to make sure, that your that your cells subviews can be displayed outside of its bounds. You need to set *clipsToBounds* for this:

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OverlapCell")

 cell?.contentView.clipsToBounds = false
 cell?.clipsToBounds = false
```

Also it is important to set the [zPosition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410884-zposition) of your cell in order to make it appear above all other cells.

```
cell?.layer.zPosition = 10
```

Hope this helps.